# Filter doesn't works in Codeiginter 4

Tags: codeigniter-4

I have using framework Codeiginter 4 (learning).I am using filter for authenticating session but filter doesn't works.Can you help how to use filter in CI4.If i have not login need to load login page...without redirecting to that specific controller.

My Filter code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Filters;

use CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\FilterInterface;

class Auth implements FilterInterface
{
    public function before(RequestInterface $request, $arguments = null)
    {
         $session = session();
         
        if(!$session->has('logged_user')){

            return redirect()->to('/Login'); 
        }
    }

    public function after(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, $arguments = null)
    {
        // Do something here
    }
}
```

At config\filters

```
public $aliases = [
        'csrf'     => CSRF::class,
        'toolbar'  => DebugToolbar::class,
        'honeypot' => Honeypot::class,
        'auth' => \App\Filters\Auth::class,
        'noauth' => \App\Filters\NoAuth::class,

    ];
```

Route.php

```
$routes->get('dashboard','Dashboard::index',['filter' =>'auth']);
$routes->get('role/index','Role::index',['filter' =>'auth']);
```

please help me to solve this problem.I have tired lot but not working for me

Comment: is the filter being ran in those controllers / methods? As in, if you place a die statement in the before function does it work?

Comment: no i didn't place die statement

Comment: Do it so we can establish id the problem is in the filter, routes or the config filter.

Comment: it is not redirecting now showing like this This page isn’t working url.com redirected you too many times.

Comment: what can i do for this